# Java Date return 1970?

Tags: java

```
long ts = 1548184720l;

System.out.println(ts + "," + (new Date(ts)).toString());
```

This prints precisely:

```
1548184720,Sun Jan 18 14:03:04 PST 1970
```

However, when I use an [Epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com/) converter, it shows the right date and time

```
Tuesday, January 22, 2019 11:18:40 AM GMT-08:00
```

Any idea whats going wrong here?

Comment: Milliseconds vs seconds

Comment: FYI, `+ (new Date(ts)).toString()` is equivalent to `+ new Date(ts)`.

Comment: Try `1548184720000l` instead.  https://www.epochconverter.com/clock

Comment: Better to use `L` instead of `l` as the latter can be easily mistaken for a 1.

Comment: `1548184720000,Tue Jan 22 20:18:40 CET 2019` ...you just assumed the wrong "scale" (1), it is 1000.

Comment: The terrible `Date` class was replaced years ago by `java.time.Instant`. Call: `Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_548_184_720L )`